WCAG testing failure because of bold font requiring a <strong> tag
I am using an accessibility checker (PowerMapper) which complains about WCAG 2: "F2: Failure of Success Criterion 1.3.1 due to using changes in text presentation to convey information without using the appropriate markup or text". I am just using CSS styling for the desired appearance of a font, not for anything to do with emphasis or semantic intent. I can’t see how to suppress this, as putting  tags around my text would actually convey false semantics; the exact opposite of what we should be trying to do. Any suggestions? Apart from complaining to the PowerMapper developers and talking to the authors of that WCAG 2.2-related note which needs qualifiers too.
See https://ssh-test.me for an example. In main.css we have something like:
h1 { font-weight: bold }


You do not need to talk to the authors of the F2 document. There is nothing in that document that is causing your issue or can be changed to fix your issue with PowerMapper. This is a decision made by PowerMapper. They have decided to be aggressive about calling this type of thing out knowing that it will produce false positives. Your beef is with PowerMapper.

I agree about talking to PowerMapper’s developers. I meant that that F2 document seems to me to suggest that every use of font-weight: bold or heavier must mean that the author intended it to mean emphasis. That is not the case.

It looks like PowerMapper SortSite has the ability to ignore rules: https://www.powermapper.com/products/sortsite/man/win/rules/#disabling-specific-rules Usually there are also ways to indicate that certain lines can be ignored in your code for these types of programs. Also, since it is a paid product, you could contact their support to get help on how to do that.

Instead of changing the font weight you could use a bolder font face. That would probably be accepted.

Just a note about this part of yours: "putting tags around my text would actually convey false semantics" -> Using a <span> tag inside another tag doesn't cause any change of semantics, and you could use a class or style attribute in it.

<h1>  elements use a font-weight of 700/bold by default. What happens, if you remove the explicit font-weight property?

Could you please add some clarity to the question by posting the exact message that PowerMapper produces for the h1? What exactly are you hoping for? A workaround for PowerMapper? Clarity about the meaning of F2?
